# Customized UIColor doesn't render correctly for UIView background or border. Why?

Tags: uibutton, background-color, uicolor

Why can't I use a customized color to paint a UIView/UIButton (background or border), yet *I can* with a stock color?

Here's my customized color:

[image]

Yet, here's the result of the backgroundColor set:
[image]

If I were to change to color to a STOCK color:
[image]

...then I get the expected result:
[image]

Why is this happening; and is there a remedy?
 ...or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for initialising the value for myColor

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:18.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0 blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: In the screenshot you have shared, you are not using floating point values.